# How to add menu in top bar in android api 22

Tags: android

I want to add a menu options (like it was in default old api's)
I created a project that the minimun is 16 and max is 22
I dont find the menu.xml file in res directory.
Didn't find how to create and use it

Comment: Post your project structure screenshot.

Comment: @Stevie..so your problem is resolved or not?

Answer (score 0):

right click on res folder select new--> create new resource directory 
and select resource type as menu, will create menu folder. then create menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right Click on res folder then click on  Android Resource Directory then you will find another dialog contains values.. scroll this to find menu

[image]