# android studio programming , error in the classes

Tags: android

```
package rms.example.com.rms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class CaddActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadd);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cadd, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

please help me in my code as i receive error in cadd (cannot resolve symbol cadd) .
my other classes also have the same problem.
this is my uni project and i am new to android programming 
thank you for your support

Comment: check in the menu folder if you have any file named cadd or not

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, from the top toolbar select Build => Rebuild Project. When it ends, the error should be fixed.

If it is not, have a look which word in the code is highlighted in red. If it is in this line:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cadd, menu);
```

Make sure you have a resource in the menu directory called 'cadd'. If not and you do not need it, just remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `cadd` named menu_layout in `res/menu` folder.

If yes then try `clean` and `Rebuild` your project.

Comment: i got a new issue instead of the old one which is Error:(30, 20) error: package R does not exist , and all class names in manifest are labeled in red and showing (can not resolve symbol "LoginActivity" validates resource references inside android XML)

Comment: @OmarAlkara You need to restart your Android Studion and clean and build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

From the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048878/6097062) create cadd file for your menu.

As you define here..
@Override

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cadd, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**cadd**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CaddActivity">

</menu>
```

Comment: i got a new issue instead of the old one which is Error:(30, 20) error: package R does not exist , and all class names in manifest are labeled in red and showing (can not resolve symbol "LoginActivity" validates resource references inside android XML)

Answer (score 0):

is cadd resource file have in your menu directory?i think the file is not there so try to add cadd menu resource file other wile use default menu_main file in place of cadd

Comment: i got a new issue instead of the old one which is Error:(30, 20) error: package R does not exist , and all class names in manifest are labeled in red and showing (can not resolve symbol "LoginActivity" validates resource references inside android XML)

Comment: clean the project and try to reinstall it.if not happening anything then mention full class name with package name in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

it was solved,
it was that i forgot to declare in the menu